# React-native Android Navigator -scene blank

Tags: android, react-native, navigator

I try to make a example of navigator ,but the scene is always blank.Some advices told me to set flex:1 to the navigator,but it doesn't work!
Here is my code: 
index.android.js:

```
'use strict';
import React, {
  AppRegistry,
  Component,
  StyleSheet,
  Navigator,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';
import Homepage from './Homepage' ;
class NavigatorTest extends Component {
  render() {
    var defaultName = 'Homepage' ;
    var defaultCom = Homepage ;
    return (
      <Navigator style = {{flex:1}}
        initialRoute = {{name: defaultName,component:Homepage }}
        configureScene = {() => {
          return Navigator.SceneConfigs.VerticalDownSwipeJump ;
        }}
        renderScene = {(route,navigator) => {
          let Component = route.component ;
          if (route.component) {
            return <Component {...route.params} navigator = {navigator} />
          }
        }} />
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('NavigatorTest', () => NavigatorTest);
```

Homepage.js

```
import React, {
  Component,
  StyleSheet,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react';
import Detailpage from './Detailpage' ;
export  class Homepage extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  _pressButton() {
    const {navigator} = this.props ;
    if(navigator) {
        navigator.push({
            name: 'Detailpage',
            component:Detailpage,
        })
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress = {this._pressButton}>
            <Text>click to jump to Detailpage!</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Detailpage.js

```
import React, {
  Component,
  StyleSheet,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react';
import Homepage from './Homepage' ;
export class Detailpage extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
  };
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  _pressButton() {
    const {navigator} = this.props ;
    if (navigator) {
        navigator.pop() ;
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress = {this._pressButton}>
            <Text>click to get back</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

I'm a newcomer of react-native ,please give me some advice ,thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try simplifying and separating your Navigator logic a bit. Debugging will also be easier this way.

```
class NavigatorTest extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <Navigator
        initialRoute={{id: 'Homepage'}}
        configureScene={this.configureScene}
        renderScene={this.renderScene}
      />
    );
  }

  configureScene() {
    return Navigator.SceneConfigs.VerticalDownSwipeJump;
  }

  renderScene(route, navigator) {
    switch(route.id) {
      case 'Homepage':
        return this.renderHomepage(navigator);
      case 'Detailpage':
        return this.renderDetailpage(navigator);
      default:
        throw new Error('No route found for id ' + route.id);
    }
  }

  renderHomepage(navigator) {
    return <Homepage navigator={navigator} />;
  }

  renderDetailpage(navigator) {
    return <Detailpage navigator={navigator} />;
  }

}
```

*Homepage.js*

```
...

_pressButton() {
  this.props.navigator.push({id: 'Detailpage'});
}

...
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer,but I got  "undefined is not a function (evaluating 'this.renderHomepage(navigator)')" , how can I find the function ?

Answer (score 0):

Separate the Navigator logic as Villeaka proposed is much more clear for reading and analysing.

The method "this.renderHomepage(navigator)" was called in "renderScene" scope, so "this" in it refer to "renderScene" not the NavigatorTest component, pass "this" to a new variable like below:

```
renderScene(route, navigator) {
var me = this;
switch(route.id) {
  case 'Homepage':
    return me.renderHomepage(navigator);
  case 'Detailpage':
    return me.renderDetailpage(navigator);
  default:
    throw new Error('No route found for id ' + route.id);
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your navigation look a little messed up, I found this video make it so easy

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jGOst2TLha0

By the way, my quick though on your code is

```
<Navigator style = {{flex:1}}
    initialRoute = {{name: defaultName,component:Homepage }}
    configureScene = {() => {
      return Navigator.SceneConfigs.VerticalDownSwipeJump ;
    }}
    renderScene = {(route,navigator) => {
      let Component = route.component ;
      if (route.component) {
        return <Component {...route.params} navigator = {navigator} />
      }
}} />
```

That "let Component" doesn't look right because variable name should not be same as "Component" library that imported on the top of your code, cause ambiguous